# Web app using Google Drive SDK without Chrome Store

Tags: google-apps, google-drive-api

I'm actually developing an application using Google Drive SDK. I don't want to create a listing or register my app into Chrome Store. Anyways, my web app is able to connect to my personal GDrive account and upload a file without Chrome Store intervention just using Oauth authentication and my own API key.

But if I want "Open with" feature in my application, is it necessary to register it in Chrome Store, or can I use it without registration?

"Open with" feature allows to open file from Google Drive directly with any application associated for its file extension. For example, 8reader app allows me to open .epub files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, currently for "Open with" functionality you need to register your app in the Chrome Web store. You no longer need a Chrome Web store app to access the Drive API (as you say). We are looking to improve this usability so users can install your app without the Chrome We store. Stay tuned!

Comment: I had this doubt because I'm going to participate into Google App Challenge 2012 and I can't upload my app into Chrome Store. Thanks Ali for your answer :)